# Why cant the code match ? PHP Response and Android

Tags: php, android

This is my java code

```
public void login() {
        try {

            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.104/rocket/assign_job.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
            //add your data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
            //int smsNum = Integer.parseInt(smsCode.getText().toString());

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("smsCode", smsCode));// $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
            //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName", rocketName));
            Log.d("smsCode ===", smsCode);

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //Execute HTTP Post Request
            //response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("PHP Response: ", response);
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(UserPage.this, "Job Assigned", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                showAlert();//testing bitbuckettt
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

This is my PHP Code:

```
<?php 
    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    if(isset($_POST['smsCode'])){
        $smsCode = $_POST['smsCode'];
        $query_search = "SELECT * FROM confirmedrequest WHERE smsCode='".$smsCode."'";
        $query_exec = mysqli_query($db->getConnection(),$query_search) or die(mysqli_error($db->getConnection()));
        $row = mysqli_num_rows($query_exec);

        if($row == 0){
            echo "failed";
        }else{
            echo "success";
            $rocketName = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->getConnection(),$_POST["userName"]);
            $sql_update = "UPDATE confirmedrequest SET jobTakenBy = '$rocketName' WHERE smsCode = $smsCode ";
            $sql_exec = mysqli_query($db->getConnection(),$sql_update) or die(mysqli_error($db->getConnection())); 
        }

    }else{
        echo "Empty code";
    }



?>
```

The PHP Response in logcat is always failed even though the code matches. I have tried to debug it for several hours but still cant solve. All I want is to run the code below (response.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) when the code matches.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the headers in order to the response to be formatted in a correct way:

```
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

if(isset($_POST['smsCode'])){
    $smsCode = $_POST['smsCode'];
    $query_search = "SELECT * FROM confirmedrequest WHERE smsCode='".$smsCode."'";
    $query_exec = mysqli_query($db->getConnection(),$query_search) or die(mysqli_error($db->getConnection()));
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($query_exec);

    if($row == 0){
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "failed";
    }else{
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "success";
        $rocketName = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->getConnection(),$_POST["userName"]);
        $sql_update = "UPDATE confirmedrequest SET jobTakenBy = '$rocketName' WHERE smsCode = $smsCode ";
        $sql_exec = mysqli_query($db->getConnection(),$sql_update) or die(mysqli_error($db->getConnection())); 
    }

}else{
    http_response_code(400);
    echo "Empty code";
}
```

Comment: I forgot to ask what version of PHP are you using, could you tell me that?